# How to access the value by index return by opencv cv::calibrateCamera?

Tags: c++, opencv

I use opencv function `cv::calibrateCamera` to calibrate my camera, and i want to access the value return by index like this `cameraMatrix.at<float>(2,2)`, but failed! The code and result is like this:

```
cv::Mat cameraMatrix = cv::Mat(3, 3, CV_32F);
cv::Mat distCoeffs = cv::Mat(1, 5, CV_32F);
cv::Mat rvecs;
cv::Mat tvecs;
double reprojectError;
reprojectError = cv::calibrateCamera(pointsOnBoard, pointsOnImg, imgSize, 
                                         cameraMatrix, distCoeffs, rvecs, tvecs);
std::cout << "Intrinsic matrix：" << std::endl;
std::cout << cameraMatrix << std::endl;
std::cout << "Value at [2,2]: " << cameraMatrix.at<float>(2,2) << std::endl;
```

The output is like this:
[image: output]

I have tried some code like this and everything is ok!

```
float tmp[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
cv Mat test = Mat(3,3,CV_32F,tmp);
std::cout << "Value at [2,2]: " << test.at<float>(2,2) << std::endl;
```

Comment: Double check `cameraMatrix.type()`after the call to `calibrateCamera` -- is it still `CV_32FC1`?

Comment: Yes, it actually is `CV_64FC1`, when use`cameraMatrix.at<double>(2,2)` i can access the value correctly! Thanks!